# Changes for an existing php code for twig template engine

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, twig

I want to read the latest threads from Invison Power Board with REST API.

I found a working PHP code, tested on my system with PHP 7.3.6, but I do not know how to use this code in Twig v2.10.0.

```php
function getRecentForumTopics() {
    $communityUrl = 'https://domain.tld/';
    $apiKey = '123';
    $endpoint = '/forums/topics';
    $vars = '?sortDir=desc&perPage=4';

    $curl = curl_init( $communityUrl . 'api' . $endpoint.$vars );
    curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH    => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD     => "{$apiKey}:"
    ) );
    $response = curl_exec( $curl );
    $values = json_decode($response, true);
    $data = [];
    foreach($values['results'] as $value) {
        $data[] = [
            'title' => $value['title'],
            'url' => $value['firstPost']['url']
        ];
    }
    return $data;
}
echo '<h2>Recent Topics</h2>';
$array = getRecentForumTopics();
echo '<ol>';
foreach($array as $key => $item) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$item['url'].'" target="_blank">'.$item['title'].'</a></li>';
    if($key == 4) {
        break;
    }
}
echo '</ol>';
```

This is the existing PHP code in Twig.

```php
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'libs/user.php';
require_once 'config.php';

$data = array(
  "WebTitle" => "name",
  //"User" => User::GetData($_SESSION['user_id'])
);

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates/');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => 'c_cache',
    'debug' => 'false'
));

echo $twig->render('test.html', $data);
```

What do I have to change that this code works in Twig?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I can add the php code in the twig php code, then the recent topics are shown at the end of the page. There are no errors, but i do not know how to write this in twig.

Comment: So what is inside `test.html`

Comment: {{ include('includes/head.html') }}

<body>
{{ include('includes/nav.html') }}

<section class="container mt-3"> 
  
    <div class="row">
 
    </div>
  
</section>
    
{{ include('includes/footer.html') }}

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twig is a templating language, so your HTML goes in your templates. Like your `test.html`. Then in PHP you get all the data needed by your template and pass it in.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'libs/user.php';
require_once 'config.php';

function getRecentForumTopics()
{
    $communityUrl = 'https://domain.tld/';
    $apiKey = '123';
    $endpoint = '/forums/topics';
    $vars = '?sortDir=desc&perPage=4';

    $curl = curl_init($communityUrl.'api'.$endpoint.$vars);
    curl_setopt_array(
        $curl,
        [
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
            CURLOPT_USERPWD => "{$apiKey}:",
        ]
    );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $values = json_decode($response, true);
    $data = [];
    foreach ($values['results'] as $value) {
        $data[] = [
            'title' => $value['title'],
            'url' => $value['firstPost']['url'],
        ];
    }

    return $data;
}

$data = array(
    "WebTitle" => "name",
    //"User" => User::GetData($_SESSION['user_id'])
    "recentFormTopics" => getRecentForumTopics() // <- This is where you are getting the data that is going to be available in twig
);

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates/');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
'cache' => 'c_cache',
'debug' => 'false'
));

echo $twig->render('test.html', $data);
```

So now that you are passing in the `data` to test.html, update your twig template to use it

```
{{ include('includes/head.html') }}
<body> 
    {{ include('includes/nav.html') }}
    <section class="container mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2>Recent Topics</h2>
                {# This is where you will use the data being passed in #}
                <ol>
                {% for recentFormTopic in recentFormTopics %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ recentFormTopic.url }}" target="_blank">{{ recentFormTopic.title }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
   {{ include('includes/footer.html') }}
</body>
</html>
```